# Filter IEnumerable according to cell in table to show dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a table in my front end that has 3 columns and 3 rows.

I want to make the cells clickable and for this to show below a table with filters according to what they clicked.

I have a list to which I would like to apply the filters based on what was clicked.
how could I do this?

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|       | Col 1    | Col 2    | Col 3    |
+=======+==========+==========+==========+
| Row 1 | Item 1-1 | Item 2-1 | Item 3-1 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| Row 2 | Item 1-2 | Item 2-2 | Item 3-2 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| Row 3 | Item 1-3 | Item 2-3 | Item 3-3 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have

```
MyList = await GetMyList();
```

I want that when I click on "Item 1-1" for example, to get below a table with a filter applied to MyList according to the conditions I want for this case (the filters would be different for each cell) such as only when EmployeeName = 'XX' or GlPeriodName = 'YY'
how could I do this?

currently I have this (which is showing the entire list):

```
@if (Model.MyList?.First() is not null)
{
    <h2>Expenditures</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Number</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Number</th>
            <th>GL Period Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var expenditure in Model.MyList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@expenditure.TaskNumber</td>
                <td>@expenditure.EmployeeName</td>
                <td>@expenditure.EmployeeNumber</td>
                <td>@expenditure.GlPeriodName</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

I understand I can filter with Model.MyList.Where(x => x.parameter = filter),  but how do I pass this parameter condition based on what is clicked on what row is clicked in the upper table?
being that the filter is not going to be the same every time such as:

if they click Item 1-1 I want

```
Model.MyList.Where(x => x.parameterX = valueX)
```

and if they click Item 1-2:

```
Model.MyList.Where(x => x.parameterY = valueXY)
```

Comment: Your question is not fully clear: you mean you want dynamic interaction? Where the user can click on something and the page changes? In razor pages that is not possible without a full page reload. You will need to do it in javascript, or use a ui framework. If you want interactive razor, look at blazor

Comment: it wouldn't be a problem to do a full reload, the part I'm having problems with is with sending a different filter to what would be the same definition of the list so it can render the "Expenditure" table again

Comment: Well, almost everybody nowadays uses the ui frameworks for this (react, angular, vue, blazor), but if you want to do it this way: what happens now if a user clicks? What are your onclick events? How do you receive the details in post? You probably need to map that in an expression factory

Comment: How do you design the `3 columns and 3 rows` table, I mean how do I know which row or which column value represent? Why Item1-1 represent prameterX and why Item1-2 represent parameterY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the table cell value as an anchor link and use `asp-route-{value}` to pass the parameter value.

Here is a simple demo:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>Col1</tr>
        <tr>Col2</tr>
        <tr>Col3</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="aa">Item 1-1</a></td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="bb">Item 2-1</a></td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="cc">Item 3-1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-glPeriodName ="dd">Item 1-2</a> </td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-glPeriodName="ee">Item 2-2</a> </td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-glPeriodName="ff">Item 3-2</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="gg">Item 1-3 </a> </td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="hh">Item 2-3 </a> </td>
            <td><a asp-page="Index" asp-page-handler="SpecificEmployee" asp-route-employeeName="ii">Item 3-3 </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
@if (Model.MyList!=null)         //it is better to change here in case of null exception.....
{
    <h2>Expenditures</h2>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Number</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Number</th>
            <th>GL Period Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var expenditure in Model.MyList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@expenditure.TaskNumber</td>
                <td>@expenditure.EmployeeName</td>
                <td>@expenditure.EmployeeNumber</td>
                <td>@expenditure.GlPeriodName</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   //for easy testing, I just hard coded.....
    public List<TestVM> MyList { get; set; }=new List<TestVM>()
    {
            new TestVM() { EmployeeName = "aa",EmployeeNumber = "1001",GlPeriodName = "dd",TaskNumber = "task1"},
            new TestVM() { EmployeeName = "bb",EmployeeNumber = "1002",GlPeriodName = "ee",TaskNumber = "task2"}
    };
      
    public void OnGetSpecificEmployee(string employeeName,string glPeriodName)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeName))
            MyList = MyList.Where(a=>a.EmployeeName.Equals(employeeName)).ToList();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(glPeriodName))
            MyList = MyList.Where(a => a.GlPeriodName.Equals(glPeriodName)).ToList();
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: this!  I was able to make it work and it was with the exact setup, passing the values with asp-route-{param}  thank you so much for helping me